# How to dump the values I'm getting from firestore to list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to get data from Firestore and add it to a list in my flutter app. But although I already put list.add inside the loop, it's still nothing inside the list.

[this is the code I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkAHM.png)

[and this is the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhitK.png)

I'm trying to add it to a list because I wanna make a dropdown menu in my flutter app.

Comment: Please avoid to put image instead of code.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading data from Firestore (like pretty much any modern cloud API call) is an asynchronous operation, which happens in the background to prevent blocking the app. So while the data is being loaded, you main code continues and prints an empty list.

Then when the data has loaded, your code inside the `then` executes, loops over the results, prints each in turn, and adds them to the list.

**To print the list after it's been populated, move the `print(listCategory);` **into** the `then` callback - one line up from where it is now.**

The general rule from this is that any code that needs the data from the database has to be inside the `then` callback, be called from there, or be synchronized by some other mechanism (such as `setState` that Sơn Dương mentioned too).

Comment: thanks! it works now. And for the images of code, yes I'm sorry. I was stuck for over 2 hours and I'm very new to stackoverflow, so this is literally my ever first question here. I won't do the same in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
 querySnapshot.docs.forEach((documentSnapshot) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = documentSnapshot.data();
             print("Name: ${data['nameCategory']}");

      });
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -2):

Don't know what state management you are using.

Basically you need `setState()` when you add it to the list.

Comment: There is no need of setState() at the moment because user is printing in console directly.

Comment: @AkshayGupta No, what you see is print in the loop. And the list is printing empty [] =))

Comment: Yes but for firstly it should print in console before showing to the user as user posted image of that if console prints successfully and there is any issue with rendering on screen then we can consider your suggestion.